# how to use trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I created a trigger but I don't know how to use it.
can someone help me?

```
create or replace trigger user_id_trigger
              before insert on library_user
              for each row
              begin
                  if :new.user_id is null then
                      select USER_ID_O_SEQ.nextval into :new.user_id from library_user;
                 end if;
end;

create table LIBRARY_USER(      USER_ID number (20) primary key not null,
                                FIRST_NAME varchar (50) not null,
                                LAST_NAME varchar (50) not null,
                                USER_BDATE date not null,
                                USER_ADRESS varchar (200) not null,
                                USER_EMAIL varchar (50) not null,
                                USER_PHONE_NUMBER varchar (25),
                                USER_STATUS varchar (20) not null,
                                USERNAME varchar (50) not null,
                                PASSWORD varchar (50) not null);
```

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a tutorial site.  The oracle documentation is a good resource.

Comment: The trigger will fire when the application inserts a row in the `library_user` table.  You'll get an error, however, because a row-level trigger cannot query the table on which it is defined.  You probably want to select from `dual` instead or just directly assign `:new.user_id` from the sequence assuming you're using a reasonably recent version of Oracle.

Comment: Besides, that `select` would return as many rows (i.e. sequence nextval's) as there are rows in the table you're selecting from, so even if it wasn't `library_user` (see Justin's comment), you'd get `too_many_rows` as you can't put that many values into `:new.user_id`. To answer your question: you don't have to do anything to use it; Oracle will use it as soon as you insert a row into the table. And, of course, fail (because of all you've been told).

Comment: Looks to me like you are trying to assign a default value to column `USER_ID` of database table `LIBRARY_USER`. There are ways to do it without using a trigger. The possible ways depend on the Oracle database version you are using. Excuse me but I couldn't find that detail in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use dual in select rather than library:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_id_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON library_user
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.user_id IS NULL
    THEN
        SELECT user_id_o_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :new.user_id FROM dual;
    END IF;
END;
```

I cant' remember which release allows you to skip the select (I think it was 11.2), but in more recent Oracle releases you can use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER user_id_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON library_user
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.user_id   := COALESCE( :new.user_id, user_id_o_seq.NEXTVAL );
END;
```